# Close the notification panel when not necessary in iOS app

Tags: feature-request, notifications, ios-app

When I open a notification and start thinking for a comment or an answer, I want to focus to it and wish the notification panel disappears for a second. I suggest you to:

- automatically hide it when it tap on an notification
- or have a button to let me hide it myself

What do you think?

Comment: This is on iPad where the inbox appears on the left and the selected question appears on the right?  Right now we hide columns when you switch to portrait (making them stack) but don't have an explicit way to do it in landscape.  I'll think about this.